# Bootstrap tooltip wrap and break

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a special situation. If I put a long text in the tooltip, it will extend and over the tooltip frame, like this.

[image]

After I add this into `.tool-inner`

```
word-break: break-all;
```

it works fine in this case.

However, it still breaks the normal sentence like this.

[image]

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25806/) to illustrate what I did.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `word-wrap` css property instead of `word-break`.

> The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$('#hoverme1, #hoverme2').tooltip();
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.tooltip-inner{
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Tooltip example
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<a href="#" id ="hoverme1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="vocabularyvocabularyvocabularyvocabularyvocabularyvocabulary">long vocabulary</a>

<br>

<a href="#" id ="hoverme2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is very long sentence, and this is very important!">Nomal sentence</a>
```

Comment: In my case I had to do word-break !important

Answer (score 1):

You should use "[word-wrap: break-word](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)" instead

Comment: It works in normal sentence, but fails in super long vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
white-space: wrap;
```

in your css instead of

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: But, super long vocabulary will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `white-space: pre-line;` from your `.tooltip-inner` and added `max-width: none;`

So now the tooltip will cover the entire view available and only wrap properly when the screen-size is less. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/t51vqoy9/) is a working fork of your fiddle.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to find a way to break line automatically.